# Android Studio: line wrapping string literals

Tags: android-studio, word-wrap, string-literals

Android Studio supports a variety of wrapping options in its `Code Style` preferences... But I seem to be unable to find a way to have Android Studio wrap string literals which exceed the specified maximum line length.

All my other wrapping works fine, but something like this..

```
                                                   |
Log.l("SOMETAG", "Some rather long log message which exceeds the line length.");
                                                   |
```

.. will be wrapped like this, whith the literal still exceeding the line length max (here marked by `|`).

```
                                                   |
Log.l("SOMETAG",
    "Some rather long log message which exceeds the line length.");
                                                   |
```

What I would expect is something like this:

```
                                                   |
Log.l("SOMETAG", "Some rather long log message " +
    "which exceeds the line length.");
                                                   |
```

**Anyone know of a way to achieve string wrapping as described??**

> Note: To the best of my knowledge all string literals concatenated using the `+` operand will be merged into single constant values by the Java compiler anyway, so although on the first glance it seems like there might be a difference in terms of the executed code there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***File***>> ***Settings***>>***Editor***>>***Java***>>  check the ***Ensure right margin is not exceeded*** box on the right>>